# Sampling from a preference table

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability

Suppose we have a table of a group of friend's preferences for food. Each person will receive a **unique** meal. What is the approach to sample from this preference table so that each time this group visits the restaurant, we satisfy their preferences based on these probabilities? The sums of the rows add up to 1, but since pizza and pasta are out of stock, I zero out their probabilities. I want this to be a sample based method (ie. Person3 will get bread most of the time, but very infrequently they might receive eggs. Person0 is likely to get Tuna, but Person1 and Person2 will probably get it quite often too, not as frequently as Person0). The frequency should reflect their own preferences and the trade offs for someone else receiving the meal. How would I approach this problem?

|  | Tuna | Pizza | Bread | Pasta | Cake | Eggs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Person0** | 0.33 | 0 | 0.1 | 0 | 0.1 | 0.01 |
| **Person1** | 0.3 | 0 | 0.2 | 0 | 0.1 | 0.01 |
| **Person2** | 0.25 | 0 | 0.2 | 0 | 0.1 | 0.01 |
| **Person3** | 0 | 0 | 0.9 | 0 | 0 | 0.01 |

Comment: It's hard to see how one could even begin addressing this situation until the meanings of these numbers are explained in a quantitative fashion (not just in terms of vague qualitative expressions like "very infrequently" or "quite often").  What exactly does "0.33" mean as a "preference," for example?

Comment: @whuber Suppose that for each person, the sum of the row adds up to 1. Pizza and pasta are out of stock in the restaurant, so we zero it out for every person. The remaining numbers are the likelihood they will receive the meal based on the sampling, before the trade-off from others receiving the meal.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to sample from a discrete distribution.  That interpretation makes the conditional aspect of the question as well as the multiple-person aspect irrelevant.  Could you therefore explain why you are introducing these complications? The meaning of "out of stock" is ambiguous: if they are always out of stock, why include these items?  If not, then you need to tell us more about how "out of stock" is related to each visit by the group.

Comment: @whuber The complications are due to the fact that this is a simplified analogy of a different problem, so the behaviour by people isn't rational.

For this example, the chef refuses to make either pizza/pasta without a specific kind of flour. There is a shortage of it and they have not been able to source it, hence these dishes are always out of stock.

I want to sample from a discrete distribution for everyone at the same time, but subject to the uniqueness constraint (so everyone roughly gets their preferences most of the time). I would appreciate advice on how to rephrase the question.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to describe your actual problem.  Analogies and abstractions usually don't go well for asking applied statistical questions because they risk omitting crucial information.

Comment: Do you really think there is insufficient information to answer this question? Using the actual problem won't add any useful information. What details are missing exactly in order to come up with some kind of approach to do a discrete distribution sample subject to a uniqueness constraint? If you can tell me what's missing, then I will be able to add whatever information is required to come to some kind of solution

Comment: As I wrote, if the question has not already been adequately answered in our posts on sampling from discrete distributions, then you need to show how your problem differs from that situation.